# Cannot convert value of type '(Date?, Bool, inout UnsafeMutablePointer<ObjCBool>?) to expected argument type '(Date?, Bool, inout Bool)

Tags: swift3

```
  var nextScheduleDate:NSDate?
  calendar.enumerateDates(startingAfter: referenceDate, matching: components, matchingPolicy: .nextTimePreservingSmallerComponents) {

    (scheduleDate: Date?, exactMatch: Bool, stop: inout UnsafeMutablePointer<ObjCBool>?) in
```

Comment: any one please give me solution?

Answer (score 0):

Do not annotate types in (callback) closures, that resolves the issue

```
calendar.enumerateDates(startingAfter: referenceDate, 
                             matching: components, 
                       matchingPolicy: .nextTimePreservingSmallerComponents) {
                                          (scheduleDate, exactMatch, stop) in
...
```

An easy way to find out the proper syntax is to comment out the line, retype the first characters and use code completion, you will see that the actual closure signature is

> (Date?, Bool, inout Bool)

That is exactly the signature the error message is referring to.

---

By the way, in Swift 3 there is a native struct `Date` for dates:

```
var nextScheduleDate: Date?
```